# trim nanoseconds to 100's of a nanosecond in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have datetime in nanosecond format in a pandas dataframe (full):

```
2017-06-30 08:53:58.940891100

2017-06-30 08:53:58.940891200
```

to get:

```
2017-06-30 08:53:58.9408911

2017-06-30 08:53:58.9408912
```

I want to trim of the last two digits so that i can keep the datetime in ticks for use in a .NET datetime object later:

at the moment I have tried this:

```
full['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f0')
```

but this just limits to microseconds with an additional zero and i need hundredth of a nanosecond precision.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Not sure if possible. You can `ns` precision or `useconds` precision in datetimes. also `full['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f0')` return strings, not datetimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want trim to `us` use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and for remove last `2` zero and convert to `strings` use `astype` with `str[:-2]`:

```
full['datetime2'] = full['datetime'].dt.floor('U')
full['datetime3'] = full['datetime'].astype(str).str[:-2]
print (full)
                       datetime                  datetime2  \
0 2017-06-30 08:53:58.940891100 2017-06-30 08:53:58.940891   
1 2017-06-30 08:53:58.940891200 2017-06-30 08:53:58.940891   

                     datetime3  
0  2017-06-30 08:53:58.9408911  
1  2017-06-30 08:53:58.9408912  

print (type(full.loc[0, 'datetime2']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>

print (type(full.loc[0, 'datetime3']))
<class 'str'>
```